# Getting Max number from multiple tables?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have multiple tables in an access project named PrivateCustomerInfo, BusinessCustomerInfo and NHCustomerInfo, each table has a column named "customerid" and I have a separate form that is used to add new customers into the designated table with a incremental customer ID. To do this I used `Nz(DMax("[customerid]","PrivateCustomerInfo` and so on for each table to basically get the largest customer ID from all the 3 tables. However, I am unsure how to compare these 3 numbers together to find the largest one and then increment by one for the new addition. I read online that you could do `Max(value1, value2, value3...)` but this doesnt work on Access VBA, any suggestions?

Comment: Adjust your table scheme to have _one_ customer table. Then, in each of the three tables, create a foreign key that relates to the customer table. Search for and study: "How to normalise a database".

Comment: `Private`, `Business`, and `NH` are types of `CustomerInfo`. Therefore, you need one `CustomerInfo` table that has a field called `Type` that contains `Private`, `Business`, and `NH`. Then you can make 3 queries that display the results in 3 separate buckets, like you want. Use those queries where you think you need these separate tables.

Answer (score 0):

I have have written my own function that can be called with a varying number of arguments and which returns the greatest of them

```vb
Public Function MaxVal(x As Variant, ParamArray y() As Variant) As Variant
    Dim max As Variant, i As Long
    
    max = x
    For i = LBound(y) To UBound(y)
        If IsNull(max) Then
            max = y(i)
        ElseIf y(i) > max Then
            max = y(i)
        End If
    Next i
    MaxVal = max
End Function
```